# Deleting user cookie

Tags: php, html

I was able to set a user cookie up properly, but it won't get destroyed or terminated upon user logout. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm still new to php and learning.

Here's my code:

**page1.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['txtusername']) && isset($_POST['txtpassword'])){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['txtusername'];
        $_SESSION['usertype'] = $_POST['usertype'];
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];
        setcookie("Activity99", $username, time()+3600);
        echo "<font class = 'user'>".$username."</font>"."<br>";
    }
?>
```

**page2.php**

```
<form method="POST" action="login.php">
    <label><?php echo "<font class = 'user'>".$username."</font>";?>
    <input type="submit" name="logout" value="Logout" class= "logout">
    </label>
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['logout'])){
        if(isset($_COOKIE['Activity99'])):
            setcookie('Activity99', $username, time()-3600,);
        endif;
    }
?>
```

Comment: `` setcookie('Activity99', "", time()-3600,); `` pass empty string in place of $username.

Comment: hello Muhammad! I tried your solution, however the user cookie was still there :(

Comment: it means i've successfully deleted the user cookie when i look at localhost from cookie settings of my browser and the name i set for the user cookie is gone, right?

Comment: U have extra comma after time ()-3600 delete that comma and try. This should work.  Reference link https://tryphp.w3schools.com/showphp.php?filename=demo_cookie4

Comment: thanks Muhammad! i don't know why but it still wouldn't work, do you perhaps think it has something to do with how i linked it with the logout button?, i'm about to give up on this.... xD

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you actually read the login state, you'd have to end your session as well:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION = [];
setcookie("Activity99", "", time() - 3600);
header("Location:  index.php?info=success");
die();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
unset($_COOKIE['your cookie name']);
```

or:

```
setcookie('your cookie name','');
```